# How to define a specific headers for exporting csv?

Tags: angular

I want to export my object to csv and with this code I found here everything works fine:

```
  downloadFile(data: any) {
    const replacer = (key, value) => value === null ? '' : value; // specify how you want to handle null values here
    const header = Object.keys(data[0]);
    let csv = data.map(row => header.map(fieldName => JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)).join(';'));
    csv.unshift(header.join(';'));
    let csvArray = csv.join('\r\n');

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff',csvArray], {type: 'text/csv'}),
    url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    a.href = url;
    a.download = "myFile.csv";
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    a.remove();
}
```

but the problem is that I want specific header names in my csv file and not the variable names of my object. (`Object.keys(data[0])`)